# Django tastypie ModelResource obj_create called on PUT request

Tags: tastypie

Sending an http put request to django-tastypie invokes 1 call to obj_update followed by 2 calls to obj_create.

I know that by overriding those functions and printing notifications to the screen.

Does anyone know why that happen and how can I make sure that only 1 call to obj_update will be invoked?

Thanks

**Update:**
Solved!

In function put_detail() in file tastypie/resources.py there is a try-except statement around obj_update. In case of NotFound exception, obj_create is called instead.